# generating tuples of ones and zeroes with a fixed number of ones

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, combinatorics, tuples

I would like to generate all the tuples of ones and zeros of a given length and with a given number of ones without generating all the possible tuples, which is impossible for tuples of large enough length (but for which the tuples with fixed number of ones is small). For example, if we consider lists of length 3, and number of ones equal to 2, I would like to directly generate {{0,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,0}} without having to generate the 8 tuples of length 3.

For those interested, I posted this related question: [Generating representatives of rotation classes of tuples of ones and zeros with a fixed number of ones](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242035/generating-representatives-of-rotation-classes-of-tuples-of-ones-and-zeros-with#242038)

Answer (score 12):

```
L[n_, m_] := Permutations@Array[Boole[# <= m] &, n]

L[3, 2]
(*    {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}    *)
```

Comment: Thanks, great reply

Comment: @EGME, if this answers your question, mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to monitor the progress of the function when there are nevertheless many tuples ... with monitor ... is there in today's functionality the equivalent of the old Combinatorica NextPermutation?

Comment: @EGME have a look at the [`NextPermutation` function on the Wolfram Functions Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NextPermutation/).

Answer (score 7):

```
With[{n = 5, k = 2}, 
 ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, n], Thread[# -> 1]] & /@ 
  Subsets[Range[n], {k}]]
```

> `{{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0,  1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1,  0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}`

Comment: Thanks, great reply

Answer (score 4):

```
f[len_,wt_] := Table[
  Boole[MemberQ[sub,i]],
  {sub,Subsets[Range[len],{wt}]},
  {i,len}
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78nxadk5oXr1NeEh9rZfs/JDEpJzXaKT8fSPqm5ialFgVGF5cm6WTGxupUgxjBpUnFqSXF0UGJeempIK1A8fKS2thanepMHSC3NvZ/QFFmXkm0Qlq0qY5RrELsfwA)

`Subsets[Range[len],{wt}]` is designed to pick out all possible `wt`-tuples of indices from 1 to `len`. We simply use `Boole` to decide when a particular index `i` is in a particular subset `sub`, and loop over all such subsets and indices.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[L2]

L2[n_, m_] := Permute[PadRight[ConstantArray[1, m], n], SymmetricGroup @ n]

L2[3, 2]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
L2[4, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0},
>  {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

Comment: quite elegant way!

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0 = Module[{ss = MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &, Subsets[Range@#, {#2}]]}, 
    SparseArray[Join @@ ss -> 1, {Length@ss, #}]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
f0[3, 2]
```

[image]

```
f0[3, 2] // Normal
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
f0[5, 2] // Normal
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
>  {1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
>  {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
>  {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
>  {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
>  {0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
>  {0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
>  {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

How can we stop without offering a recursive idea? Compact the binary elements into integers for fast processing:

```
intperm[n_, 0] := {0}
intperm[n_, 1] := Array[2^# &, n, 0]
intperm[n_, m_] := 2^n - 1 - # & /@ intperm[n, n - m] /; m > n/2
intperm[n_, m_] := (intperm[n, m] = 
  Join[2 intperm[n - 1, m - 1] + 1, 2 intperm[n - 1, m]])
binperm[n_, m_] := IntegerDigits[#, 2, n] & /@ intperm[n, m]
```

Interestingly, for large $n$, the time taken is entirely dominated by `IntegerDigits`.